# 2009 Vibe 2.4L rear driver-side brake heating up

Tags: brakes, vibe

My Vibe has recently had its rear brake pads and rotors replaced, but nothing else in the brake system.  Yesterday I drove for about 20km and noticed a burning smell and a lot of heat coming off of the rear driver-side brake.  I checked again this morning after a 5km drive to work and the same thing happened.  The car isn't driving badly and it doesn't pull to one side.  The e-brake handle is loose and has lots of play in it.  I have a few questions:

- Could this be due to a loose e-brake cable?  If so, I feel it should affect the passenger side as well, and that side is not heating up.
- I have a 2500km round trip coming up in two days.  I am very concerned that I won't be able to take it to a mechanic in time.  I'm aware that this will probably destroy my brakes, but **is it unsafe**?  I am going to try to get it into my mechanic today, but if he can't look at it soon enough I don't know what option I have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unsafe, don't drive this car 2500km unless you get it fixed. The heat could cause a brake failure, it's just not worth the risk. At the very least you'll get a warped rotor and you could end up needing to replace several components at high cost.

You either have an emergency brake with isn't releasing, or a brake caliper which isn't releasing, which is more likely as you've just had them serviced. A likely culprit is the slider pins on the caliper being rusted up or needing to be lubricated. So call your mechanic and tell them the situation, a good mechanic will free up time and fix for free under warranty as it is a problem with their work.